# MS CA certificate generation with individual keys, C#

Tags: c#, ssl, cryptography, x509certificate, ca

At the moment I am developing an Web application that will serve as a MS CA interface for certification enrollment. The error comes out after the app have generated the csr and send it to CA. Certificate should have the following structure:

```
Serialnumber = UserId, CN = FirstName SecondName, O = Organization, P = PhoneNumber
```

Here is a real example:

```
Serialnumber = 200554041000, CN = John Farel, O = SRL Insign, P = 60182209, C = MD
```

Error shown is:

> CertEnroll::CX500DistinguishedName::Encode: The string contains an
>   invalid X500 name attribute key, oid, value or delimiter. 0x80092023
>   (-2146885597)

If I remove P or change it on Phone everything goes well and certificate is being generated.

And second!! :) After certificate have been generated subjects DN contains everything bun not Serialnumber and Phone.

I am using MS CA on MS Windows Server 2008, CA Cryptography Service Provider:
Microsoft Software Storage Provider, Hash Algorithm: SHA1.

For more information leave a comment. Thank you anticipated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Few things to know:

1) "PhoneNumber" attribute is named "Phone", not "P" or whatever else.

EDIT:

2) I checked SDK and, unfortunately, it appears that it is not possible to include Phone RDN attribute in the subject. From header file only these attributes can be added:

```
//+--------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Name properties:

#define wszPROPDISTINGUISHEDNAME   TEXT("DistinguishedName")
#define wszPROPRAWNAME             TEXT("RawName")

#define wszPROPCOUNTRY             TEXT("Country")
#define wszPROPORGANIZATION        TEXT("Organization")
#define wszPROPORGUNIT             TEXT("OrgUnit")
#define wszPROPCOMMONNAME          TEXT("CommonName")
#define wszPROPLOCALITY            TEXT("Locality")
#define wszPROPSTATE               TEXT("State")
#define wszPROPTITLE               TEXT("Title")
#define wszPROPGIVENNAME           TEXT("GivenName")
#define wszPROPINITIALS            TEXT("Initials")
#define wszPROPSURNAME             TEXT("SurName")
#define wszPROPDOMAINCOMPONENT     TEXT("DomainComponent")
#define wszPROPEMAIL               TEXT("EMail")
#define wszPROPSTREETADDRESS       TEXT("StreetAddress")
#define wszPROPUNSTRUCTUREDNAME    TEXT("UnstructuredName")
#define wszPROPUNSTRUCTUREDADDRESS TEXT("UnstructuredAddress")
#define wszPROPDEVICESERIALNUMBER  TEXT("DeviceSerialNumber")
```

3) avoid "Microsoft Software Key Storage Provider" provider use in your .NET application, because it is CNG provider and `X509Certificate2` do not support CNG (shame on .NET). Though, it is recommended to use KSP for CA keys (when there is no HSM).

Comment: Hello, :) actually it works thery well with SERIAL NUMBER but not with Phone... it is still not displayed!

Comment: um..looks like it will not. I'll check with Microsoft. I'll post an update if I get anything relevant from them.